# Stack overflow when adding an entity with multiple one-to-one relationship with the same table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an issue when adding entities with multiple one-to-one relationship with the same table in Entity Framework Core. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252077/adding-a-second-one-to-one-relationship-with-the-same-table-in-entity-framework) question I have the following things:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PreviousId { get; set; }
    public Article Previous { get; set; }
    public int? NextId { get; set; }
    public Article Next { get; set; }
}
```

In the `OnModelCreating` of the `DbContext` as I have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("ab");
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ArticleEntityTypeConfiguration());
}

public class ArticleEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Article>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Article> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Articles");

        builder.HasKey(table => table.Id);
        builder.Property(table => table.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.HasOne(table => table.Previous).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Article>(table => table.PreviousId);
        builder.HasOne(table => table.Next).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Article>(table => table.NextId);
    }
}
```

And when adding a new article I get a stack overflow error and the app crashes. I add an article with the following code:

```
public Task AddNewArticleAsync(Article article)
{
    var newArticle = new Article();

    article.Next = newArticle;
    newArticle.Previous = article;

    await _dbContext.Programs.AddAsync(article);
}
```

Do you know how can I avoid that error? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but did you try [InversePropertyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)?

Answer (score 0):

if you add a new article,the `PreviousId/NextId`  should be null or an existing `Article.Id`.If your Artice.Id is increasing, the previousId is the max id of the existing records.

Below is a demo to save new articles:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Article article)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int minArticleId = _context.Articles.Max(a => a.Id);
        var previous = await _context.Articles.Where(s => s.Id == minArticleId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        article.PreviousId = minArticleId;
        _context.Add(article);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        previous.NextId = article.Id;          
        _context.Update(previous);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(article);
}
```

Comment: Actually the navigation is not like that. There are kind of threads so the PreviousId is not necessary the min id in the database. That's why the previous article, or at least the previous article id, must be an input of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

So I continue investigating about this and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728016/self-referencing-many-to-many-relations#answer-54401037) answer which helped me to fix the issue. The trick was to change the `OnModelCreating` of the `DbContext` to:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Article> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Articles");

    builder.HasKey(table => table.Id);
    builder.Property(table => table.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    builder
        .HasOne(table => table.Previous)
        .WithOne() // <-- one of this must be empty
        .HasForeignKey<Article>(table => table.PreviousId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder
        .HasOne(table => table.Next)
        .WithOne(table => table.Previous)
        .HasForeignKey<Article>(table => table.NextId);
}
```